# Vert.x EventLoop Thread Block Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr

Tags: apache-kafka, vert.x, kafka-producer-api, event-loop

I'm experiencing very weird thread block of more than 4 second when searching for dns entry (?) while initiating kafka producer, exception:

```
2019-02-11 10:00:33,982 WARN [vertx-blocked-thread-checker] io.vertx.core.impl.BlockedThreadChecker - Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-0,5,main] has been blocked for 4172 ms, time limit is 1000 ms
io.vertx.core.VertxException: Thread blocked
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1324)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1277)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1193)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1127)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1077)
    at java.net.InetSocketAddress.<init>(InetSocketAddress.java:220)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:53)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:406)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:304)
```

It occurs once a while (not every time) 
Can I disable ipv6 lookup programmatically in vertx ?
How can I make this error disappear ?

Comment: Are you developing on OSX ? Then you're probabling hitting this http://justthesam.com/2016/10/fixing-java-net-inet6addressimpl-lookupallhostaddr-slowdown/

Comment: With IPV6 protocol you are not finding the host, so you can have two problems. You have a bad host, but as you said it works sometimes, the problem should be in your computer, so check it. But, if you want to disable IPV6, that configuration is in Java configuration, soy run java with Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

Comment: No, deploying the application to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server

Comment: @LucasMilotich I tried this flag before - it created some other issues for us, there is another way maybe programmatically in vert.x to disable ipv6 address lookups only ?

Comment: Vertx Web Client options inherit Http Client options so you can set any one of them, but I'm no so sure if you can specify the ip protocol. Try to read http java docs to see if there is any cfg in the http options of the http client. Did you try to disable ipv6 from the computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding the flag "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true" it fixed the problem but opened some other issues with `InetAddress.getLocalHost()` which returns localhost\127.0.0.1 for hostname\ip ...
to solve this I had to edit /etc/hosts in machines to:

```
# This file is automatically generated by our bootstrap script.
<MACHINE_IP> <MACHINE_HOSTNAME>   # <-- Ordering ...
127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
# ::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback <MACHINE_HOSTNAME>   <-- IPV6 must be disabled
```

after disabling all IPv6 section from /etc/hosts the correct hostname and ip was resolved and my program initiated properly